# Foundation 5, Top bar not act like mobile on tablet

Tags: mobile, zurb-foundation, tablet

On my site, I want to the topbar works same on tablet that shows on mobile, but it shows same as pc version on tablet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is where the initial 'Top-Bar Breakpoint' behaves. Check out the CSS customizer: http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation